# What's the browser support for a shorthand null/undefined check in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

A few years ago I remember using something like this in some Javascript:

```
someFunc(someVar || 42);
```

...as a shorthand in case someVar is null or undefined. I vaguely remember IE 8 choking on this. Maybe I'm remembering incorrectly, so can anyone confirm or deny browser support issues with this type of Javascript statement?

I don't have access to IE 8 at the moment so I can't test it myself. Also, if this question isn't a duplicate, then it might be useful to others. Lastly, is there a name for this type of conditional statement?

Comment: It's not really checking for null/undefined. It's using the first of the 2 that returns `truthy`. Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: IE8 does not choke on that code. There are no browser support issues there.

Comment: And FYI, Microsoft has free virtual machines you can download and use to test old versions of IE. http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/

Comment: Cool, never knew about those!

Comment: Yeah, they're *really* handy. They have lots of great tools on http://dev.modern.ie . Surprised me when I came across it.

Answer (score 0):

That sort of thing runs in IE 10. What you could do, if IE 8 is a hard requirement, is a ternary operator:

`funcCall(someVal ? someVal : 42)`

Comment: There's no need for special code for IE8. The original code will run just fine.

Comment: I suppose Mike Thomsen never really said that IE8 was not supported, but it was definitely implied given that was what my question was asking. Too late, my upvote is locked in.